# Хостинг бота на Python

Tags: python, api, хостинг, бот

дорогие пользователи сайта, написал небольшой скрипт который должен отправлять запросы API на определённый сервер, запуская на пк все работает, решил поставить это дело на хостинг но все не так уж просто, возникло сразу куча проблем, как поставить этот скрипт на хостинг что бы он работал 24/7 ? (я новичок, не знаю как ставить бота на хостинг, и на какой)

````
import requests

while True:
    requests.get('https://tf2.tm/api/v2/ping?key=*****************')
    sleep(180)```

вместо звёздочек должен быть API KEY с сайта tf2.tm
````

Comment: Поставь на heroku или pythonanywhere. В интернет найдешь статьи, как залить)

Comment: На любой VPS с линуксом, инструкций по автозапуску навалом в том числе на этом сайте

Comment: @Sherlock PythonAnywhere блокирует почти все запросы в сеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Устанавливаешь на VPS хостинг Linux, советую для начала Ubuntu, либо же Debian.
Подключаешься по SSH
После этого устанавливаешь python и nohup.
Далее nohup python3 ./script.py, закрывешь консоль, и всё, у тебя запущен этот скрипт, для того чтобы его отключить
ps -A
Находишь процесс nohup
kill -9 pid процесса
Это самый простой способ, если тебе нужно посерьёзнее, почитай про сервисы и venv.